# systemctl suspend, Call to Suspend failed: Access denied

Tags: systemd, suspend, polkit

After a recent update on an Ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ systemctl suspend
Call to Suspend failed: Access denied
```

Some weeks ago worked fine this way, **without** any root privileges.

On journal:

> `dbus-daemon[1310]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.991" (uid=1000 pid=683426 comm="systemctl suspend " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="SuspendWithFlags" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1" (uid=0 pid=1512 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind " label="unconfined")`

[From](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=666725#c16)

> The "rejected send message" is the dbus equivalent of "permission denied". And the reason why the permission is denied depend on the sender, the destination, the interface and the member.

A simple search return mostly issues related with hibernate. One way  ([1](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1152337#p1152337), [2](https://askubuntu.com/a/1201779/349837)) could be to add NOPASSWD to sudoers file (**not** the same), but seems a [polkit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd#Power_management) issue.

What package update cause this behavior? There is other (maybe more elegant) solution other than editing sudoer file?

**Edit**:

```
$ grep -ri org.freedesktop.login1.suspend /usr/share/polkit-1/
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy:        <action id="org.freedesktop.login1.suspend">
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy:        <action id="org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions">
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy:                <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.imply">org.freedesktop.login1.suspend</annotate>
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy:        <action id="org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-ignore-inhibit">
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy:                <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.imply">org.freedesktop.login1.suspend</annotate>
```

```
$ grep -i suspend /usr/share/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.login1.conf
                       send_member="Suspend"/>
                       send_member="SuspendThenHibernate"/>
                       send_member="CanSuspend"/>
                       send_member="CanSuspendThenHibernate"/>
```

For some reason, using other similar regular user `systemctl suspend -i` works flawlessly.

Tried also [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Polkit#Disable_suspend_and_hibernate) with `Result.YES`.

Using `busctl monitor`:

```
‣ Type=error ...  Sender=org.freedesktop.DBus  Destination=:1.4594
  ErrorName=org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied  ErrorMessage="Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.4594" (uid=1000 pid=636652 comm="systemctl suspend -i " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="SuspendWithFlags" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1" (uid=0 pid=1512 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind " label="unconfined")"
  MESSAGE "s" { STRING "Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.4594" (uid=1000 pid=636652 comm="systemctl suspend -i " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="SuspendWithFlags" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1" (uid=0 pid=1512 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind " label="unconfined")"; };
```

---

I had the same issue with `systemctl reboot`/`RebootWithFlags`. Same solution, added to `/usr/share/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.login1.conf` (part of `systemd` package).

Comment: Did it work before within the same installation? If not, permissions or group membership assignments may have been different.

Comment: @pell `systemctl suspend`/`reboot` were working without root. It was a [D-BUS Bus Configuration](https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/bionic-security/main/amd64/systemd/237-3ubuntu10.13/file/usr/share/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.login1.conf) issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### D-Bus

Check that there are no dbus policies in `/usr/share/dbus-1/system.d` or `/etc/dbus-1/system.d` that explicitly deny unprivileged access to members of `org.freedesktop.login1` related to the system suspension.

You can use the following policy to allow unprivileged users to invoke `org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend` and `org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.SuspendWithFlags`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?> <!--*-nxml-*-->
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
        "https://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
        <policy context="default">
                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.login1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager"
                       send_member="Suspend"/>
 
                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.login1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager"
                       send_member="SuspendWithFlags"/>
        </policy>
</busconfig>
```

Save this policy file as `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.login1.conf` and reload the dbus daemon with `systemctl reload dbus`.

### Polkit

You can add the following rule to allow regular users to suspend the system without authentication.

```javascript
// vi: ft=javascript
Array.prototype.includes = function (variable) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) { if (this[i] === variable) return true; }
  return false;
}

polkit.addRule(function (action, subject) {
  if (
    [
      "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend",
      "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-ignore-inhibit",
      "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions"
    ].includes(action.id) &&
    // Allow user named "user_name" or users in group "wheel" to suspend this system, 
    // Modify accordingly to suit your system    
    (subject.user == "user_name" || subject.isInGroup("wheel"))
  ) {
    return polkit.Result.YES;
  }
});
```

**Change "user_name" to your username**

Save this rule as `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/01-suspend.rules`, it will take effect immediately.

Comment: I've found some mentions to `suspend`, add to my post. Tried moving `login1.suspend-ignore-inhibit`, `<allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>` to yes. I also your code, but stills return access denied without root rights. Also restarting polkit service. The issue seems to happen only with one user. Only found `~/.local/share/polkit-1/` without nothing interesting

Comment: what is output from `grep -R -C 10 SuspendWithFlags /usr/share/dbus-1/system.d /etc/dbus-1/system.d`

Comment: No output, nor with `-i`

Comment: I've updated the answer with a D-Bus policy file, does it work for you?

Comment: Also, the dbus policy file, which contains `SuspendWithFlags`, is part of systemd. If it's missing, your system may be corrupted. In this case, run `debsums`.

Comment: I `debsums -cs` to all the packages from the output of `dpkg -S /etc/dbus-1/system.d /usr/share/dbus-1/system.d`. Didn't return any output.

Comment: does this file exist `/usr/share/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.login1.conf `.

Comment: Yes, `send_member=Suspend, SuspendThenHibernate, CanSuspend, CanSuspendThenHibernate`. Works on other similar user, so is something user-wide. Nothing rare on dconf. I suspect a conflict related with `brew`.

Comment: The problem is in the policy with the dbus member `SuspendWithFlags`, does the policy file `/usr/share/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.login1.conf` contain any reference to this member? If it does not, you most likely have a corrupted systemd package, as this part of the file comes directly from upstream. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/56506988f208e7f96ae0bfd83d1ff9436cb174f5/src/login/org.freedesktop.login1.conf#L159

Comment: IDK neither why this only happened with only with my user, nor why `debsums` doesn't detect any corruption, but adding that portion on `/usr/share/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.login1.conf`, right below Suspend member did the trick. Please add this solution to your answer to get the deserved bounty.

Comment: I've already included it in an edit. See the ### D-Bus section, adding the SuspendWithFlags to `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.login1.conf` is basically the same as overriding the default policy, with the added benefit of not inferring with package files.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo systemctl suspend` because you might need to be root.

Comment: That undoubtedly will work, but I had always suspended as a regular user.  I used with a shortcut and stop working.

Answer (score -3):

if you dont want to write sudo all the time make a alias in your shell config by adding `alias "systemctl suspend"="sudo systemctl suspend"`